# Excruciatingly slow graphics on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, graphics-card, performance, ati-mobility-radeon

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but for most of the past year that I've been testing Windows 8, I haven't been able to play games.

When I was on the Developer Preview it was working until an ATI Driver update came out. It hasn't worked since.

The problem occurs, when loading (for example): [Nexuiz](http://www.alientrap.org/games/nexuiz). Each frame loads unbearably slowly, as does the sound.

I thought it would work today since I just installed the released version of Windows 8 over Consumer Preview, but it still isn't working. Also tried installing the latest [Windows 7] drivers from ATI's site. Same trouble.

---

#### System specifications (Dell Studio 17)

- Intel Core i7 740QM @ 1.73GHz
- 6.00 GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 664MHz (9-9-9-24)
- Dell Inc. 0J509P (U2E1)
- ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4650 (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM v1.1) (Dell)

---

**How do I get games—such as Nexuiz—to work on Windows 8?**

Comment: Could you use the old ATI driver from the first Development Preview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to worry legacy hardware are still getting support
http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/catalystlegacywin8.aspx

"Contrary to some rumors, AMD will not be discontinuing support for their legacy products. Rather, a new Quarterly Driver Release schedule will be put into place."

Quote source: http://www.hardwarecanucks.com/news/video/amd-moves-quarterly-hd-2000-hd-3000-and-hd-4000-driver-releases-nixes-windows-8-updates/

Comment: Awesome, thanks a heap. I tried looking on the AMD site again and still wasn't linked to it. Thanks to you I played my first decent game of Nexuiz on my laptop in two years `:P`. Anyways, time to close the game and get back to work `:V`!

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck. Radeon HD 4000 series are not supported from ATI for windows 8, so unless MS decides to write the drivers, you won't be able to game with this OS.

http://www.techspot.com/news/48321-amd-drops-windows-8-support-for-radeon-hd-4000-and-older.html

Comment: It might be nice to indicate that AMD decided not to support this particular product line.  There isn't any technical reason that it can't be supported by a generic driver.